# Header location is not working on live server

Tags: javascript, php, html, header

I Have one registration and payment page. program flow is like registration > confirmation > payment. After validation and calculation in registration page need to go to confirmation page.
My code is

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

include("header.php");
include("ini.php");
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Brunei');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=900');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $error = 0;
//validations

if ($error <= 0) { 
//do some calculation
header('location:confirm.php');
}
}
<?php
ob_flush();
?>
```

Control entered in to if ($error <= 0) clause, but stay on the registration page.

I tried many ways like

```
 header('location:confirm.php', true, 302);
```

instead of

```
header('location:confirm.php');
```

removed

```
ob_start() and ob_flush()



add exit() after  header()
```

then it goes to blank page.

Also try to use

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="confirm.php";';
        echo '</script>';
```

Then the control goes to confirmation page but url seems to be as registration.php

But header('location:confirm.php'); is working fine in my local server. Anybody please help me to resolve this issue.. Is there any alternate way for header(). Looking forward to you guys.. Thanks

Comment: Please stop using code snippets for PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Also try to change header('Location:confirm.php');
(Note L is capital since its work in your local server may be problem with strict php type try this once)

Answer (score 0):

```
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'confirm.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
```

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. Your issue is that Location requires an absolute URI, you can't give it just a path.

Comment: why don't you echo  $host  and $uri and tell me what they say?

Comment: I can go to my website in 2 ways. one is http://www.test2015.org/Registration/registration.php and http://test2015.abc.org/Registration/registration.php . host is 
 test2015.abc.org ,uri is /Registration

Answer (score 0):

use `ob_end_flush()` at the end. This should work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issues for years but today i discovered that u don't have to have any html  or blank space before the header word .Try it out