# Redirect a page to another folder

Tags: php, apache

I have a page by name of barbad.php  it is in folder /p/ but  now i have created a page with the same name in another folder ,it is in folder /play/ and i want that when in search engine find the link like below :

```
music/p/barbad.php?Albumid=695&artistid=184&trackid=6091
```

then user redirect to address below:

```
music/play/barbad.php?Albumid=695&artistid=184&trackid=6091
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

in `p/barbad.php`you can simply redirect to `play/barcode.php`. You need to use the same query string so `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is append with redirection url.

```
     <?php
        $queryString =  $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];   
        header("Location:../play/barbad.php?".$queryString);
        die();
      ?>
```

Comment: thanks,i put the code in p/barbad.php but it does not redirect ,the complete address is mydomain/music/play/barbad.php

Comment: I have tried this on my machine and it worked. You can also use absolute url  `header("Location:mydomain/music/play/barbad.php?".$queryString);` what result you get..??

Comment: i use the absolute url also like header("Location:mydomain/music/play/barbad.php?".$queryString);

Comment: no,there is not error,but the main page in /p folder load without any error.

Comment: put it on top of the page and `die()` after `header();`

Comment: i tested on localhost and it redirect but on server no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73895/discussion-between-kaveh-and-tintu-c-raju).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748692/header-location-is-not-working-on-live-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398808/header-redirect-not-working-on-server-but-working-on-localhost can you please refer these

Answer (score 1):

Try, it using .htaccess file,

```
#.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^music/p/barbad\.php(.*)$ http://yourdomain/music/play/barbad.php$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache mod_rewrite

Add to htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch ^music/p/barbad.php?Albumid=([0-9]+)&artistid=([0-9]+)&trackid=([0-9]+)$ http://domainname/music/play/barbad.php?Albumid=$1&artistid=$2&trackid=$3 [R=301,L]
```