# PHP header works on localhost but not on server

Tags: php

I have tried all solutions of stackoverflow but not working for me. The page stays at index. But registration header is working. if I manually go to stdwelcome.php, it opens which means login is successful and no problem with database. Same problem is also in stdwelcome.php. When I logout, it stays in the same page and does not go to the index.php. I have also tried absolute path of the page, but the problem exists.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();

include_once 'oesdb.php';

if(isset($_REQUEST['register']))
{
    header('Location: register.php');
}
else if($_REQUEST['stdsubmit'])
{
    $result=executeQuery("select *,DECODE(stdpassword,'oespass') as std from student where stdname='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name'],ENT_QUOTES)."' and stdpassword=ENCODE('".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES)."','oespass')");

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if(strcmp(htmlspecialchars_decode($r['std'],ENT_QUOTES),(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES)))==0)
        {
            $_SESSION['stdname']=htmlspecialchars_decode($r['stdname'],ENT_QUOTES);
            $_SESSION['stdid']=$r['stdid'];
            unset($_GLOBALS['message']);
            header('Location: stdwelcome.php');
        }
        else
        {
            $_GLOBALS['message']="Check Your user name and Password.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_GLOBALS['message']="Check Your user name and Password.";
    }
    closedb();
}
?>
```

Comment: None of the code you posted is related to going back to the index.php on a logout: Also post that code please.

Comment: Check your curly braces, looks like there is an extra one.

Comment: typically when `header('Location: ...);` does not work correctly, it is because headers are already sent, even if it is just a simple echo, or whitespace before your opening tag, ie. `.   <?php`

Comment: @Naterade: no problem with curly bracket, I am just posting part of the code. It is absolutely working fine on localhost

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748692/header-location-is-not-working-on-live-server

Comment: @Sean can you please point out where i am getting wrong

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Its just same problem. header not working. In this code it is not going to stdwelcome.php after login

Comment: Ok, since the information provided does not match the question I am going to take a guess here: If you logout, the code does not get a rowcount>0 (if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)) and so will never hit your header line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in place of your header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.assign('your desired location');
</script>
```

Note:close php before script tag and open php after closing script tag

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks a lot. My Problem is solved now. No more worries.

Answer (score 1):

Try using absolute path in 
header('Location': 'http://example.com/stdwelcome.php') Replace example.com with your domain

Comment: Already done that. But not working. Previous answer worked for me.